# How to use provider to update class with multiple instance?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

[image]I am learning the provider package. I have a class called person.
    `Person(this.name,this.amount);`

The person is displayed in a list.

How do I pass the particular instance of a person to the change notifier so that I can update the person amount?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having the Provider class be on `List<Person>`?  Then you could update a specific instance, and the change would be notified downward.